# Is storing XML/JSON in a MySQL Column ALWAYS bad?

Tags: mysql, xml, database-design

I have an event organizer where a user can create one or several custom excel-like spreadsheets associated with an event. The event will also have some notes, and dates, and other basic info that fits well into a SQL databse. Obviously, I can't create a table for each user's spreadsheet. The data in the spreadsheet will NOT have to relate to anything in the database. The sheet itself will relate to the user and the event, but the data inside is self-contained with no strict data types.

- So is it bad to just have a column with XML if it doesn't have relations?
- Is there a better place to store it besides local storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not necessarily bad. It's just that when you store a blob of XML or JSON to a field, you can't do anything to it, except for reading and overwriting. No queries, joins, grouping on items within this blob.

If you're fine with this and you do all your processing in the app anyway, then go ahead, store XML in the database.

Comment: The only dynamic thing I can think of is the user could hit a "save" button and then I could send the SQL query with the new XML.

If you have any other suggestions of how to store a custom spreadsheet, let me know, but otherwise thanks. I have spent hours looking for a thread, but they all talked about XMLs where you'd want to query specific fields.

Comment: If you're not doing anything except 'read all' / 'rewrite all' operations, then you don't really need any suggestions. It's easy as pie! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can install software, install a NoSQL DB for storing XML/JSON. e.g. Cassandra, MongoDB, Redis

They are better to handle that sort of access. Pretty much anything you need to store a blob, you are better off storing it in something other than MySQL since MySQL is not optimised as a key/value store.

Comment: I am still learning a fair amount, I've tried researching NoSQL (specifically MongoDB) lately because other than knowing what it is I have no idea how to best implement it. Can it integrate well with MySQL (Like a Users table and Events table for determining access, etc.)? The rest of my data works well in MySQL. Or would it be best to just move everything into a NoSQL?

Comment: I would just keep track of the **Documents** in NoSQL the K/V store. So, it is a simple [UserIDFromMySQL]:[DocumentName] kind of key pairing is probably the simplest way to do it. Then just grab a list from the NoSQL of the documents assigned to the user (or in MySQL if you prefer, although it doesn't handle lists of IDs well).